# class level validation rules across multiple properties

Tags: c#, class, validation

I have properties of a class that I want to apply some validation rules to.

I want to create a custom validator that:
- checks to see if the number and/or the address is present
- and if neither are present then return a message "This is required"

Currently I have:

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(Course), "NumberOrAddressValidator")]
public class Information {
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
public static ValidationResult PhoneOrWebAddressRequiredValidator(string name, ValidationContext context)
        {
            if (Course.WebAddress == null)
            {
                return "Phone or web address is required";
            }
            else if(Course.PhoneNumber == null)
            {
                return "Phone or web address is required";
            }
            else
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

        }
```

Am I thinking about this correctly? I am a bit stuck on understanding what "return ValidationResult.Success" exactly does. And currently it is throwing an error on returning a string (the message I want to return).

Any tips and help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you should go for Expressive-Annotation instead of making custom validation. Install NuGet Package by running in PMC

PM> Install-Package ExpressiveAnnotations -Version 2.9.5

Your code will look like.

```
 public class Information
{
    [RequiredIf("Address==null", ErrorMessage = "Number or Address is Required")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("Number==null", ErrorMessage = "Number or Address is Required")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shahid but in this example, I want to use a custom validator as I am practicing that.